# Form Submit stop refresh

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, submit

Okay so this is a page which is loaded in using an ajax navigation the page loads fine its self I am trying to make it so that when the page submits it doesn't refresh the whole page. I've looked around for a while and still can't find a fix it.

```html
<head>
  <script>
    $(document).on('submit', '#changePassword', function() {
      $("#content").load("core.home");

      return false;

    });
  </script>
</head>
<?php if( !preg_match( "/index.php/i", $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF'] ) ) { die(); } ?>

<form action="" method="post" id="changePassword">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxhead purple purple">
      <strong>Change password</strong>
    </div>
    <?php if( $_POST[ 'submit'] ) { try { $oldpassword=$ core->clean( $_POST['current_password'] ); $oldpassword_enc = $core->encrypt( $oldpassword ); $newpassword = $core->clean( $_POST['new_password'] ); $newpassword_enc = $core->encrypt( $newpassword ); if( !$oldpassword or !$newpassword) { throw new Exception(
    "All fields are required." ); } elseif( $oldpassword_enc != $user->data['password'] ) { throw new Exception( "The password you entered does not match the one we have on record." ); } else { $db->query( "UPDATE users SET password = '{$newpassword_enc}'
    WHERE id = '{$user->data['id']}'" ); echo "
    <div class=\ "square good\">"; echo "<strong>Success</strong>"; echo "
      <br />"; echo "Password successfully changed!"; echo "</div>"; $db->query( "INSERT INTO logs VALUES (NULL, 'Changed Password <font color=\ "51c833\"><b>Success</b></font>', NULL, '<b>{$user->data['fullUsername']}</b> ({$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']})', '3') "
    ); } } catch( Exception $e ) { echo "
    <div class=\ "square bad\">"; echo "<strong>Error</strong>"; echo "
      <br />"; echo $e->getMessage(); echo "</div>"; $db->query( "INSERT INTO logs VALUES (NULL, 'Changed Password <font color=\ "FF0000\"><b>Fail</b></font> Reason: {$e->getMessage()}', NULL, '<b>{$user->data['fullUsername']}</b> ({$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']})',
    '3') " ); } } ?>

    <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
      <?php echo $core->buildField( "password", "required", "current_password", "Current password" ); echo $core->buildField( "password", "required", "new_password", "New password"); ?>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="box" align="right">
    <button class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>

<?php echo $core->buildFormJS('changePassword'); ?>
```

Comment: what actually you want to do? explain it in detail.

Comment: The code here is a separate file it is loaded into an ajax box when the form is submitted it refreshes the whole site back to index.php I don't want a site wide refresh to occur

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `e.preventDefault` to stop the default behaviour of a submit button (i.e to reload on submit)

```
$(document).on('submit', '#changePassword', function(e)
 {  
  e.preventDefault();

 });
```

Comment: So I've changed my script at the head of the page to this but it still reloads the page completly

Comment: Can you provide your code on jsfiddle or the url of your website? You should wrap it in a `$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Your code here
});`